# GetId doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I run the following code with FosUserBundle in Symfony2:

```
var_dump($myUser->getId())
```

But it returns nothing, while `var_dump($myUser->getUsername())` works. Why does `getId()` not work?

My getter in my `user.php`:

```
public function getId()
{
    return parent::getId();
}
```

Comment: can you post your user class ? do you override parent id property too ?

Answer (score 0):

According to  https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md this is how your user class should look like.

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

You don't need to call

```
return parent::getId();
```

With the above class

```
return $this->id;
```

should work.